# Issue with using StorageFolder in a Unity UWP App deployed on a Hololens

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, smb, storagefolder

I'm trying to access a SMB Share Drive from a Unity, UWP app on the hololens and I've tried to follow the approach in the following link:

[How to access local network (SMB) in UWP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50931099/how-to-access-local-network-smb-in-uwp)

I've defined the required (Capabilities, Share Targets and File Type Associations) in the Package.appxmanifest, as you can see in the following screenshot:

[image]

In my Unity script, I define the following:

if ENABLE_WINMD_SUPPORT && !UNITY_EDITOR

```
StorageFolder folder = await StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(@"\\DESKTOP2GEQQ3D\FolderModels");
```

The "await" never returns, and I receive the following error:

"FileNotFoundException: Unable to find specified file.".

Any ideas why the await never returns and is stuck forever?? Surely if StorageFolder wasn't able to access "FolderModels", I would receive an "UnauthorizedAccessException" error.

My SMB Share Drive is visible to all other networks, my Hololens is on the same network as the SMB Share Drive...I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: From your description, the SMB shared folder "\\DESKTOP2GEQQ3D\FolderModels" is visible to all other networks. Have you verified if the same code is working well in a pure UWP project? Where are you running the test? On real device or emulator? For toubleshooting, could you please provide the Unity version and the HoloLens device info? Especially using Unity 2018.4.x LTS for HL v1 development.

Answer (score 0):

The solution you referenced is not completely correct. I would recommend you checking the answer in MSDN forum: [LINK](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e822c960-f15d-4789-9ff2-040212d0a67c/uwpaccess-a-file-on-a-network-drive?forum=wpdevelop).

The main points for fix as below:

1. The right capabilities we need to access network drive has been described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions?redirectedfrom=MSDN#accessing-additional-locations)

   Please double check the **Universal Naming Convention (UNC) folders** part.
   The Proximity capability is irrelevant in our case.
2. The Share Target declaration is not the right one we need to set. Instead, please add **`File Type Associations`** declaration, see the official guidance: [Handle file activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation)

For example, if we need to access .jpg and .txt files in the SMB folder, add the capabilities:

```
<Capability Name="internetClient" />
<Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer"/>
<uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication"/>
<Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
```

And set `File Type Associations` declaration:

```
<uap:Extension Category="windows.fileTypeAssociation">
          <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="smbfolder">
            <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
              <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
              <uap:FileType>.jpg</uap:FileType>
            </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
            <uap:DisplayName>SMBFolder</uap:DisplayName>
          </uap:FileTypeAssociation>
        </uap:Extension>
```