# Unity Load Media Files From PC At Runtime

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm developing an app for HoloLens 2 with Unity version 2020.3.3f1
This app should be able to load some medical data from a PC at runtime, thus I need to implement a connection with a PC when running the application on HoloLens, and to take some files from it.
I'm struggling a lot in finding some useful information to do this, thus I'd be really glad if someone can give me some suggestions on how to achieve this.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most direct way to do that, you can establish a TCP connection between HoloLens 2 and PC, then build a PC server app to respond to the file request from HoloLens Client App.

Another way, instead of coding your own server app, creating a file-sharing using the SMB protocol on your PC, and access this drive from HoloLens, for more detail please refer to this thread: [Issue with using StorageFolder in a Unity UWP App deployed on a Hololens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406259/issue-with-using-storagefolder-in-a-unity-uwp-app-deployed-on-a-hololens)